# Problem while executing a Makefile

Tags: permissions, makefile, mkdir

i'm installing the Rocket-Chip repository.
I'm following the instructions from https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip.
The instructions are:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip.git
$ cd rocket-chip
$ git submodule update --init
$ export RISCV=/path/to/riscv/toolchain/installation

$ git clone https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-tools
$ cd rocket-tools
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
$ export RISCV=/path/to/install/riscv/toolchain
$ export MAKEFLAGS="$MAKEFLAGS -jN" # Assuming you have N cores on your host 
system
$ ./build.sh
```

When i launch the last command, i have these errors and warnings:

```
Makefile:5347: warning: rewriting of the instruction set for "check-   
recursive"
Makefile:4181: warning: ignoring of the instruction old set for "check-   
recursive"
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
...
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory "/path": Permission denied
make[3]: *** [Makefile:4130: install-dist_ulinkDATA] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for non terminated processes....
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory "/path": Permission denied
make[3]: *** [Makefile:4929: install-info-am] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4489: install-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4181: install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:4483: install] Error 2
```

I've checked all the permission of the files and the folders the makefile is interested to, but it doesn't work at all.
Someone can help me please?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "the point to build the shell"? can you [edit] your question to include a lager portion of the error output?

Comment: I've specified the commands i've used.

Comment: What actual paths did you substitute for `/path/to/riscv/toolchain/installation` and `/path/to/install/riscv/toolchain`? (And what value of `N` did you substitute in `-jN`?)

Comment: I selected N=2, and for the first path i've choosen the folder rocket-chip, and for the second rocket-chip/rocket-tools

Comment: Well the error message `cannot create directory "/path": Permission denied` suggests that you are trying to create things directly in the `/` directory

Comment: You're right. Thanks everyone

Comment: I'm facing the same issue! @Andrea13 were you able to resolve this?